# C# basic loop iterator

Tags: c#

Okay here's the question, using C# I need to create a program using a loop which asks for a number then displays the first 1000 multiples of it. So basically if the person enters 17 it would show 17, 34, 51, 68, 85 etc.

I've got so far this code.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  Console.WriteLine(i * number);
```